# Normalize Numpy matrix rows by their average

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'd like to normalize matrix rows by their average and I wrote this code for it

```
m = np.matrix(
    [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [2,3,2,5,3],
     [5,5,5,3,2]])

for row in m[:,]:
    average = row.sum() / row.shape[1]
    row = row / average
```

In for cycle, I divide row with average. But this division doesn't change matrix m. How can I achieve this normalization in the most simplest and smartest way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compute the row-wise average, and the compute `m/average`:

```
In [36]: average = m.mean(axis=1)

In [37]: average
Out[37]: 
matrix([[ 3.],
        [ 3.],
        [ 4.]])

In [38]: m/average
Out[38]: 
matrix([[ 0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.        ,  1.33333333,  1.66666667],
        [ 0.66666667,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  1.66666667,  1.        ],
        [ 1.25      ,  1.25      ,  1.25      ,  0.75      ,  0.5       ]])
```

Note that if your matrix contains `NaN` values, then you could use `np.nanmean(m, axis=1)` instead of `m.mean(axis=1)` to compute the row-wise mean while ignoring NaNs.

Comment: And `m /= m.mean(axis=1)` to modify `m`, but considering `m`'s dtype is `int` they will end up with ints rather than floats.

Answer (score 1):

For `in-situ` change in `m`, you can convert to `float` datatype (if not already) and then use [`np.divide`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html), like so -

```
m = m.astype(float)
np.divide(m,m.mean(1),m)
```

Sample run -

```
In [294]: m
Out[294]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [2, 3, 2, 5, 3],
        [5, 5, 5, 3, 2]])

In [295]: m = m.astype(float)

In [296]: np.divide(m,m.mean(1),m);

In [297]: m
Out[297]: 
matrix([[ 0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.        ,  1.33333333,  1.66666667],
        [ 0.66666667,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  1.66666667,  1.        ],
        [ 1.25      ,  1.25      ,  1.25      ,  0.75      ,  0.5       ]])
```